# Freebody diagram for an object rolling up a frictionless incline?

Tags: rotational-dynamics

I am confused about the direction of the force that causes the ball to come to rest once it reaches maximum height for a ball rolling up a frictionless incline. I understand that the translational kinetic energy is converted to potential energy so this should happen but I don't know what the free body diagram would look like.

Answer (score 1):

If the incline is frictionless then there's only gravity and normal force. That's it.

None of these alter the rotation (since they both act through the rotational centre). So the rotation will never stop!

> the force that causes the ball to come to rest

When you say this you mean that the *translational motion* comes to a rest, only. Because the *rotational speed* will remain constant and the ball will spin on spot everywhere.

Comment: I probably should have worded it more clearly. Say an object is initially rolling on a surface with friction then rolls up a frictionless incline and reaches its maximum height. It's linear motion will come to rest momentarily at the maximum height. For an object in motion to come to rest, there has to be some opposing force. What is the direction of this opposing force relative to the incline?

Comment: @sadpwner The opposing force is gravity (specifically gravity's parallel component). That's it.